# Debian intel + nvidia optimus hdmi output not recognized

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, hdmi, optimus

I have an Asus N56VM laptop, with optimus graphics (Intel + Nvidia). It's got an HDMI connection, and I do have a monitor connected to it.
In Windows, I can have dual monitor, and so can I in Ubuntu, without a problem.

My problem is, I'm trying to get it to work in Debian, and I have no idea how.
I think it's either some driver or kernel problem, because xrandr does not even detect the HDMI output. It works even in lightdm or slim.

Here's what I get running xrandr in Ubuntu:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      59.9*+   39.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
  1680x1050 (0x46)  119.0MHz
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock   64.7KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock   59.9Hz
  1280x1024 (0x49)  108.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x52)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x56)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x57)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0x5f)   25.2MHz
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
```

and here's the debian counterpart:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.91*+  39.94  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lsmod in ubuntu:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               16384  1 
isofs                  40960  1 
uvcvideo               90112  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         49152  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
arc4                   16384  2 
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
ath9k                 147456  0 
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
coretemp               16384  0 
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              720896  1 ath9k
cfg80211              540672  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   483328  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0 
aesni_intel           172032  0 
asus_wmi               24576  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_intel          32768  3 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
nouveau              1400832  1 
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    90112  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
i915                 1052672  3 
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
joydev                 20480  0 
drm_kms_helper        122880  2 i915,nouveau
serio_raw              16384  0 
drm                   344064  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
lpc_ich                24576  0 
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
shpchp                 40960  0 
video                  20480  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2 
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    24576  0 
usb_storage            69632  4 uas
ahci                   36864  3 
psmouse               118784  0 
alx                    36864  0 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mdio                   16384  1 alx
```

and in Debian:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17063  0 
bnep                   17431  2 
bluetooth             374429  7 bnep
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
cpufreq_conservative    14184  0 
cpufreq_stats          12782  0 
cpufreq_userspace      12525  0 
cpufreq_powersave      12454  0 
nfsd                  263032  2 
auth_rpcgss            51211  1 nfsd
oid_registry           12419  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                12511  1 nfsd
nfs                   188136  0 
lockd                  83389  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                45542  1 nfs
sunrpc                237402  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
nouveau              1122419  1 
asus_nb_wmi            20664  0 
asus_wmi               22781  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          12818  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                12515  1 nouveau
i915                  837138  3 
iTCO_wdt               12831  0 
iTCO_vendor_support    12649  1 iTCO_wdt
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    12951  0 
intel_powerclamp       17159  0 
intel_rapl             17356  0 
coretemp               12820  0 
kvm_intel             139116  0 
arc4                   12536  2 
kvm                   388635  1 kvm_intel
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    12978  0 
aesni_intel           151423  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67127  1 
aes_x86_64             16719  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    12757  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath9k                  90244  0 
gf128mul               12970  1 lrw
uvcvideo               79005  0 
glue_helper            12695  1 aesni_intel
ath9k_common           21746  1 ath9k
ablk_helper            12572  1 aesni_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
cryptd                 14516  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ath9k_hw              391172  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
videobuf2_core         47787  1 uvcvideo
ath                    26067  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
v4l2_common            12995  1 videobuf2_core
psmouse                99249  0 
videodev              126451  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
mac80211              474277  1 ath9k
serio_raw              12849  0 
media                  18305  2 uvcvideo,videodev
evdev                  17445  14 
snd_hda_intel          26327  0 
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
cfg80211              405538  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
snd_hda_codec         104463  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
ttm                    77862  1 nouveau
i2c_i801               16965  0 
rfkill                 18867  5 cfg80211,bluetooth,asus_wmi
snd_pcm                88662  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  7 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
lpc_ich                20768  0 
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
drm_kms_helper         49210  2 i915,nouveau
mfd_core               12601  1 lpc_ich
drm                   249955  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           12751  2 i915,nouveau
i2c_core               46012  8 drm,i915,i2c_i801,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,v4l2_common,nouveau,videodev
shpchp                 31121  0 
wmi                    17339  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
battery                13356  0 
button                 12944  2 i915,nouveau
ac                     12715  0 
video                  18096  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
processor              28221  0 
fuse                   83350  1 
autofs4                35529  2 
ext4                  473802  3 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82413  1 ext4
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 44460  0 
hid                   102264  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sg                     29973  0 
sd_mod                 44356  5 
sr_mod                 21903  0 
crc_t10dif             12431  1 sd_mod
cdrom                  47424  1 sr_mod
crct10dif_generic      12581  0 
usb_storage            56215  1 
ahci                   33291  2 
libahci                27158  1 ahci
crct10dif_pclmul       13387  1 
crct10dif_common       12356  3 crct10dif_pclmul,crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif
ehci_pci               12512  0 
xhci_hcd              148881  0 
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
ehci_hcd               69837  1 ehci_pci
libata                177457  2 ahci,libahci
scsi_mod              191405  5 sg,usb_storage,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
alx                    36175  0 
mdio                   12599  1 alx
usbcore               195340  6 uvcvideo,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
thermal                17559  0 
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
thermal_sys            27642  5 video,intel_powerclamp,thermal,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
```

What can I do to change this?

Comment: [Debian: Bumblebee](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee)

Comment: thank you. i already know about bumblebee. It's meant to give you the possibility of using your nvidia graphics card to run something. Not have multi monitor. If you notice, in the above ubuntu lsmod, there is no bumblebee module, and no nvidia module either. that means it's not related to bumblebee, just probably some configuration i'm missing. Bumblebee is not even installed in ubuntu, and i still get the dual monitor working. I just want to reproduce that in debian.

Comment: Searching the web, I found this page: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup  Then I tryed "intel-virtual-output' (that allows using the HDMI even when it is wired to the NVidia board), however, on debian it does not seem to have this "VIRTUAL1" output declared in the X server (I am stuck there).

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same position. I've got Dell e6430. On mint 17.3 it was not a problem to have it work. Even in nvidia settings I could choose wheter to run with Primus or not. On Debian the only solution that works for me to have output from Nvidia on HDIMI is to disable Optimus in BIOS.

Comment: This answer does not state any source for its claim. Neither does it provide with some real solution.